# Cuales son los problemas que se pueden dar con el tiempo, al asignar mas memoria al heap de java?

Tags: java, out-of-memory-error

Tengo una aplicación que me esta dando problemas de Heap Space, mirando lo que hacia con el profiler de netbeans y otras apps más, me di cuenta que hay instancias que están consumiendo casi un total de 2,2 gb de memoria dependiendo del caso va variando el consumo total y generando el típico error:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space.
```

Bueno la primera solución que se me ocurrió por obviedad fue aumentar la memoria de java, pero antes de hacer eso tuve que hace algo mas importante mirar el código de la aplicación y ver si se podía optimizar, bueno el problema no pasaba por una optimización, habian instancias que consumian mucha memoria y es imposible hacer que consuma menos memoria en esas instancias.

**Por ej:** Un caso equis que se daba era cuando se tenia que grabar un caso de pruebas con mas de 300 imágenes esto provoca que se dispare el error.

Bueno tras haber analizado el código y ver por que se consumía tanta memoria en algunos casos. se llego a la conclusión de que había que aumentar la memoria del HEAP de java si o si.

tras toda esta conclusión necesito que alguien me diga, cual es el problema que puede ocurrir a largo plazo si aumento la memoria de java.

ya que leyendo en varios foros y blogs, estos decían que esto es una solución temporal.

**Por que es una solución temporal?**
**Cuanto tiempo aguantara la aplicación con estos cambios de ser así?**

Se aumento la memoria de la aplicación y se hicieron pruebas para ver como se comportaba y funciona bien. pero tengo la inquietud con las preguntas mencionadas anteriormente.

Atento a sus comentarios y ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depende de cada caso. Para las personas que dicen que es una solución temporal debe ser porque ellos sufrían de un leak de memoria, es decir que el GC no podía liberar la memoria adecuadamente y solo aumentaba el consumo de memoria, sin importar cuánta memoria se le asignara a la aplicación.

Si en tu caso sabes que, por ejemplo, con 4 GBs de memoria tu aplicación correrá sin problemas, entonces esta no sería una solución temporal, sería la solución. Claro está, siempre y cuando tu código no tenga un leak de memoria y lo hayas evaluado apropiadamente.